# How to know last inserted id, if the database is not availiable?

Tags: c++, database, solid-state-drive

I have a  system that writes records in a database. If the database is down however, the system fails-over and writes data to csv files (one file per table).

The question is how to permanently store last inserted order id, such that
if the database is not available on application load, I will know from what Id to resume writing? I am concerned about ruining the SSD from constantly updating a number in a file.

---

Further details on the problem:

The data that need to be saved in the database:

```
struct Order{
   int id;
   string date;
   string clientName;
   vector<OrderItem> items;  
}
```

The database has an `Orders` table and an `OrderItems` table. OrderItems has a foreign key to Order.id

I want to be able to bulk insert in the database.
For example if the average order has 5 items. Inserting 1000 records in Orders followed by 5000 records in OrderItems.

From experimenting I found that I can't use bulk-insert and also be given the lastInsert id for each of the inserted rows. I need to know the Order.id because its a foreign key in OrderItems.

So I am left with the option that OrderId must be a number assigned to and maintained by my application and not the database.

Further more, my application has to be able to switch to writing to CSV files, which can be imported to the database later when it becomes available.

Let's say the application has written in the database upto OrderId 12345. Then the application crashes, and the db is offline. The application restarts, and I can't connect to the database. How will the application know the last inserted Id, so that I can write proper ids to the Orders.csv and OrderItems.csv files?

Comment: I don't really understand your issue. If your ids are maintained by the application, then what exactly is the problem? You just need to insert Orders first, and then associated OrderItems. If your ids are generated on the database side, then you insert a single Order and then associated OrderItems. Storing last id seems like a weird hack for something so simple. Not to mention that it will completely fail when dealing with more than 1 producer.

Comment: Next, I'm not sure how you want to deal with duplicates (just because the db is down, doesn't mean it didn't process the data). My advice is to maintain ids on the application side, not in the form of int (global order will be hard to enforce), but in the form of UUIDs/GUIDs or maybe some natural id (if available). As for SSD: these have around 10 years of lifespan nowadays. But to be sure nothing bad happens, you should create backups (and maybe even replicate the data in a real-time manner to some other disk/machine/cloud).

Comment: Also I don't think that options I've mentioned will affect SSD in a visibly different way. All of the data has to be stored on the disk after all. It is likely that whatever you do will not affect disk much (everything has to be written no matter what). With modern DB engines there might be a difference due to transcation log, but I wonder whether this is a big difference. Of course I might be wrong. To be 100% sure I encourage you to measure iops yourself and decide then.